# how to check and record URL redirction?

Tags: java, python, redirect

I writing some web-spider now. I want to crawl a bunch of pages from the web. I have succeed part of my goal, with hundreds of URL link stored on my hand. But those links are not the final link. That means, when you put a URL in a web browser like Google Chrome, the URL would be automatically redirected to another page, which is what I want. But that only work in a web browser. When I write code to crawl from that URL, redirection would not happen.

Some example:

given  (**URL_1**):

```
 http://weixin.sogou.com/websearch/art.jsp?sg=CBf80b2xkgZ8cxz1-SgG-dBH_4QL8uVunUQKxf0syVWvynE5nPZm2TPqNuEF6MO2xv0MclVANfsVYUGr5-1b3ls29YYxgU27ra8qaaU15iv7KVkBsZp5Td27Cb2A24cIwEuw__0ZHdPeivmW-kcfnw..&url=p0OVDH8R4SHyUySb8E88hkJm8GF_McJfBfynRTbN8wjVuWMLA31KxFCrZAW0lIGG1EpZGR0F1jdIzWnvINEMaGQ3JxMQ33742MRcPWmNX2CMTFYIzOo-v8LrDlfP2AnF54peD-GxvCNYy-5x5In7jJFmExjqCxhpkyjFvwP6PuGcQ64lGQ2ZDMuqxplQrsbk
```

put this link in a browser, it would be automatically redirect to (**URL_2**):

```
http://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzA4OTIxOTA4Nw==&mid=404672464&idx=1&sn=bdfff50b8e9ac28739cf8f8a51976b03&3rd=MzA3MDU4NTYzMw==&scene=6#rd
```

which is a different link.

But put this in python code like:

```
response=urllib2.urlopen(URL_1)
print response.read()
```

that auto-redirection does't happen!

In a word, my question is: given a URL, how to get the redirected one ?

Some body give me some java code, which work in some other situation, but doesn't help in mine:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public void test()throws Exception {
        String expectedURL ="http://www.zhihu.com/question/20583607/answer/16597802";
        String url = "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=ByBJLpHsj5nXx6DESXbmMjIrU5W4Eh0yg5wCQpe3kCQMlJK_RJBmdEYGm0DDTCoTDGaz7rH80gxjvtvoqJuYxK";
        String redirtURL = getRedirectURL(url);

        if (redirtURL.equals(expectedURL)) {
            System.out.println("Equal");
        }else{
            System.out.println(url);
            System.out.println(redirtURL);
        }
    }

    public String getRedirectURL(String path) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(path).openConnection();
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        return conn.getHeaderField("Location");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Main obj = new Main();
        obj.test();
    }
}
```

It would print out **Equal** in this case, which mean that we can now get `expecteURL` from `url`. But this would work in the former case.( I don't know why, but looking carefully in to the **URL_1** above and that `url` in the java code, I notice that there is some interesting difference:  there is a snippet `.../link?url=...` in the `url` in above java code , which would probably means some *direction*. But in the **URL_1** above, it is `.../art.jsp?sg=...` )

Answer (score 1):

Look for `follow_redirects` option. In python, you can do it e.g. with `requests`

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://example.com', follow_redirects=True)
print response.url

# history contains list of responses for redirects
print response.history
```